# Has anyone developed a TeamPilgrim (Pending Changes) extension for Visual Studio 2015 or 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I have been holding out on Visual Studio 2010 for too long, because I really don't like the new Pending Changes window (nor the flat interface, but that's a different issue!). However, I recently had to install Visual Studio 2017 (though 2015 is available to me as well). Microsoft has confirmed [they are not going to bring back the checkboxes](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/5610294-bring-back-the-old-pending-changes-window), so I did some searching and found a great add-in someone made for [VS2012](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StanleyGoldman.TeamPilgrim) and [VS2013](https://github.com/itsho/TeamPilgrim) called TeamPilgrim which brings back the 2010-style Pending Changes window with checkbox list, as a dockable window.

I downloaded the source for TeamPilgrim for 2012 and tried to get it working in 2017 and failed (I didn't really know what I was doing) :(

The author of TeamPilgrim 2012 has abandoned it and the author of TeamPilgrim 2013 doesn't post contact information, but I believe that one is abandoned as well.

I am just wondering if anyone else has or knows of continued work on this extension and has it working in later editions of Visual Studio, since it's exactly what I am looking for and would make using new Visual Studio much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the extension is open source on GitHub, you could download the source code and upgrade the extension to support visual studio 2015.

please double click .vsixmanifest file. in the design view and select Install Targets, the Version Range for your extensions is currently probably [12.0]. To add support for VS 2015, change it to [12.0, 14.0]. 
[image]

If you want to upgrade the extension to support vs2017, you need to upgrade from extension manifest version 2 (VSIX v2) to the new version 3 VSIX manifest format (VSIX v3). for more steps, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017

Update:

I download the source code from GitHub and modified it, which support vs2015.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvaNEnglADDgQjP5HgUgPN1I1mI

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great comment and the link. I have been trying to get this extension to work in newer VS and have been unsuccessful. When I try to upgrade the VSIX, it breaks a large number of references, and after trying to replace all the references with DLLs I found on my computer, the newer replacements don't seem to work very well. (Example: The type or namespace name "ProjectState" does not exist in "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common" and "Interop type "Constants" cannot be emdedded"). I have no experience with extensions and was hoping someone had already solved it. I'll keep trying!

Comment: Update: I was able to fix all the errors and get it compiled and installed. Unfortunately it still doesn't work (Pending Changes window, for example, doesn't "see" any of my changes and remains blank). So I still can't use the extension yet, and am still hoping someone else has it working, but I will upvote your answer for your "teach a man to fish" approach.

Comment: I download the source file, open it with visual studio 2015, modify the reference with local dll in visual studio 2015, and modify the install targets to 14.0, it works on my side. I update the reply with the project I have modified.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional and I was able to get the Team Pilgrim extension running as you described. However, VS crashed whenever I clicked the check-in button in Pending Changes, so I found and fixed that bug in TeamPilgrim and documented it on the 2012 extension's github page. Apparently though, this will require a bit more work to get running in VS 2017. Since I asked about either version, and it works in 2015, I will accept your answer. Thank you for the help!